# Under the rain vs In the rain

Tags: prepositions

In most cases people say **stand in the rain**, I can understand it but can we say **stand under the rain**, will it make any sense?

Comment: Use "in the rain", because the rain is around you, not just above you. Something like "in the water".

Comment: @user3169 Still there's **under water**

Comment: That would be *underwater*, under the surface of the water. Rain doesn't have such a quality. Still you can be "in the water", meaning water surrounds you in general.

Comment: @user3169 No, I swear I heard under water and under sea. I know underwater. Still I got the point. Both are correct but only **in** is appropriate.

Comment: I think you will find that the context is different for these. You might check actual examples, because I would expect "under *the* water" or "under *the* sea".

Answer (score 2):

You can say

> stand **under** the rain

and it will be understood, and people will realize you are a non-native speaker.

> stand **in** the rain

is used since the rain kind of surrounds you (it falls on and around you), whereas

> **under** threatening skies

firmly places you below the sky.

Comment: So **under the rain** is incorrect?

Comment: It's not "incorrect" *per se*, since it's understandable and grammatically correct, but it would not be used by a native.